# How to implement a custom cache provider with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, provider

I am migrating a [MonoRail](http://castleproject.org/monorail/index.html) application to [ASP.NET MVC 1.0](http://www.asp.net/mvc/). In my original application I wrote a custom cache provider (a distributed cache provider using [memcached](http://www.danga.com/memcached/)). In MonoRail this task was very easy because the framework used interfaces and there is [ICacheProvider](http://api.castleproject.org/html/T_Castle_MonoRail_Framework_ICacheProvider.htm) that looks like this:

```
public interface ICacheProvider : IProvider, IMRServiceEnabled
{
    void Delete(string key);
    object Get(string key);
    bool HasKey(string key);
    void Store(string key, object data);
}
```

An instance of this interface is available in every controller action. So, all I had to do was to implement a custom cache provider that uses memcached and tell
MonoRail to use my cache provider instead of the default one. It was also very easy to mock and unit test my controller.

In ASP.NET MVC 1.0 there's the System.Web.Abstractions assembly (name looks promising) that defines the [HttpContextBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.aspx) like this:

```
public abstract class HttpContextBase : IServiceProvider
{
    ... 
    public virtual System.Web.Caching.Cache Cache { get; }
    ...
}
```

I don't understand how the Cache property used here is an abstraction of a cache provider. It is the legacy sealed [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) class. It seems that I am not the only one [struggling to mock](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/10/29/testing-fun-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx) out the classes in the framework.

I am very new to the ASP.NET MVC framework and I must be missing something here. I could write a CustomBaseController that uses an ICacheProvider interface that I define and
all my controllers derive from this base class, but if there's a more elegant (ASP.NET MVCish) solution I would be glad to implement it. I've noticed that HttpContextBase implements [IServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iserviceprovider(VS.71).aspx). Where's the [GetService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iserviceprovider(VS.71).aspx) method going to look for services? Can this be easily mocked?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Cache doesn't have an official abstraction or provider, but you can easily build one:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/zowens/archive/2008/08/04/cache-abstraction.aspx
- http://memcachedproviders.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/15983#58762

ASP.NET 4.0 includes an [output cache provider abstraction](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/27/extensible-output-caching-with-asp-net-4-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) (AFAIK *not* a general cache abstraction but only for *output* caching)

Comment: @mausch, that's exactly what I ended doing. The only thing that is not clear from the first post is how to inject the cache abstraction in the HttpContext pipeline using an IoC for example so that it is accessible from everywhere.

Comment: I wouldn't try to inject it in HttpContext. Instead, just inject you r abstraction (ICache or whatever it's called) in your controllers.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is outdated. See [ASP.NET 4.0: Writing custom output cache providers](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/11/19/asp-net-4-0-writing-custom-output-cache-providers.aspx).

Comment: It's not outdated. The *output cache* is now pluggable (I did add that to my answer back in 2010), but not the general cache.