# Caching the data from behind pages in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, caching

I've simplified this example a lot, but the theory is there.

I have a table which contains content for a page - there might be 3 or 4 rows per page.

Every time a page loads, the database is queried and the content loads.  This is fine generally, but on busy sites this can hit the database quite a lot.

I'm looking for some kind of "caching" solution - that ideally doesn't use much in the way of memory (ideally it'll be file system based).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Anything wrong with [ASP.NET's built in Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Also might want to check out [How to implement a custom cache provider with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873355/how-to-implement-a-custom-cache-provider-with-asp-net-mvc)

As a final suggestion, you may want to look into building a filesystem-based cache using the System.Caching classes documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching%28VS.100%29.aspx).  From a brief perusal, it looks like you'd probably want to inherit from ObjectCache.

Comment: Fundamentally, no - it's just consumes quite a lot of memory, if there's a way to make it file system based...

Comment: The maximum amount of memory that it uses can be configured, if that helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.cachesection.percentagephysicalmemoryusedlimit.aspx

Comment: But then if it peaks at the maximum amount of memory...where is it being stored?

Comment: It isn't.  It will discard items from the cache and free up memory once the cache grows too large.

Comment: I think that would be a problem for us as the cache may be huge, and so it's going to be constantly re-loading items in and out of the cache...