# is there anyway to tell the .net cache to use the app fabric server instead of local memory?

Tags: asp.net, .net, appfabric

We managed to use the App Fabric Caching Server for storing our `Outputcache`, without changing our code, only with configuration. And it's working very well.

Is there any way to do the same with the .Net Cache (`HttpContext.Current.Cache`) ? without changing our code, only config.

Thanks

Comment: I see that this is possible for `Session` but nor for `Cache`, at least doesn't seem to me like a matter of modifying the `Web.config`. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790859.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no provider abstraction ([`ProviderBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.provider.providerbase.aspx)) for the **HttpContext Cache**. There is for **OutputCache** and **Session** as indicated by @Icarus. It will require changing code.

Here are a couple ideas for you...

1. Use AppFabric [`DataCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.applicationserver.caching.datacache%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) instead of `HttpContext.Current.Cache`. See [Hanselmans example](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingConfiguringAndUsingWindowsServerAppFabricAndTheVelocityMemoryCacheIn10Minutes.aspx).
2. Convert anything using **HttpContext Cache** (*Application Cache*) to **Session** (*User Cache*).
3. See [related SO post regarding building a custom Cache provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/875220/175679).